# Why is this not correct (fermat number)

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If $$F_{n}=2^{2^{n}}+1$$

then compute $F_{10}$ mod $14$,

I thought since $2^{10}=2$ mod $14$

that it would be equal to $5$ mod $14$

but apparently it is $3$.

Anyone can help explain?

Comment: Why are you taking the mod of the exponent?

Comment: I didnt know you couldnt do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at what happens to powers of $2$ modulo $14$.  They are:
\begin{align*}
2^1&=2\\
2^2&=4\\
2^3&=8\\
2^4&=16\equiv 2\\
2^5&=32\equiv 4\\
2^6&=64\equiv 8
\end{align*}
Observe that the pattern repeats every $3$ terms.  Therefore, the power should be computed modulo $3$, not $14$.  You need to compute $2^{10}\pmod 3$ and use that as the exponent on $2$, add $1$, and take that result modulo $14$.

Comment: Well displayed.  (+1)

Answer (score 0):

The order of $2$ mod $7$ is $3$ (i.e. $2^3 = 8 \equiv 1 \mod 7$), so 
$2^{2^{10}} \mod 7$ depends on $2^{10} \mod 3$, not mod $14$.
And then mod $2$, ...

Answer (score 0):

Note that since $2^4\equiv2\pmod{14}$, it follows that

$$2^n\equiv2^{n\mod3}\pmod{14}$$

From here it's easy to see that $2^{10}\equiv1\pmod3$, so

$$F_{10}=2^{2^{10}}+1\equiv2^1+1=3\pmod{14}$$